# Regex to extract info from a string

Tags: java

I have recently started making an ircbot, and in my ban command I have a need to extract the name of the target and the mode.

There are to different modes + and -

So one example of a string would look like

```
!!ban + Sjele
```

or

```
!!ban - Sjele
```

How would I find and get the mode, either - or + with a regex and the target in this case Sjele?

I tried this to in the online regextester regexpal and it did not work, this is as close as I could get with my low knowledge of regex's

```
((.*)(+| -)(.*))
```

Using matcher and pattern when this regex is working, I would like 3 variables:

- pref (should be !!ban)
- mode (either - or +)
- target (in this case Sjele)

Thanks
(English is not my first language and I do have troubles getting understood, if I were unclear please tell me and I'll try to explain better.)

Comment: a regex is overkill here.  Just use String methods to pull the mode and name out.

Comment: the regex is \!\!ban ([\+|\-]) (.*)

Answer (score 0):

A regex is somewhat overkill for this situation. I created a method that takes a `String` to test and that will return a `String` with the character you are looking for, or `null` if there is no match:

```
public static String getBanStatus(String s1)
{
    if (s1.contains(Character.toString('+'))) return "+";
    if (s1.contains(Character.toString('-'))) return "-";
    else return null; // Or return something meaning no match was found
}
```

---

If you **need** a regex, the one Pshemo gave should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for regex you can try with `!!ban ([+\\-]) (\\w+)`. In group 1 you will have + or - and group 2 will contain name of banned/unbanned user.

Here is simple example

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("!!ban ([+\\-]) (\\w+)").matcher(
        "!!ban - Sjele");
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + ":" + m.group(2));
```

---

If you are using Java7 you can name your groups for nicer code

```
!!ban (?<operation>[+\\-]) (?<userName>\\w+)
```

and use it like this

```
Matcher m2 = Pattern
        .compile("!!ban (?<operation>[+\\-]) (?<userName>\\w+)").matcher(
                "!!ban - Sjele");
if (m2.find())
    System.out.println(m2.group("operation") + ":" + m2.group("userName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the + and - symbols like so \+ \-

Otherwise they have a special meaning to the regex compiler.

Comment: Only `+` is special character in OP regex. `-` is special in character class (`[...]`) but outside of it it is normal character.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
!!ban\s*(\+|\-)\s*(\w+)
```

You will have **mode** on the first group and **target** on the second.